# How to GROUP BY CASE with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to get the count of a.clmNo based on the a.stat value displayed on one row.  I am currently getting 3 rows returned since I have a count of 5 a.clmNo over 3 different a.stat values, which makes sense since I am grouping by s.stat.  How can I change my query so that I don't have to group by s.stat and instead get the results returned on one row?

Current results:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+
| pend_claims | assnd_claims | qa_ready_claims | qa_claims | closed_claims |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+
|       0     |       3      |        0        |     0     |       0       |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+
|       0     |       0      |        0        |     1     |       0       |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+
|       1     |       0      |        0        |     0     |       0       |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Desired results:

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|pend_claims | assnd_claims | qa_ready_claims | qa_claims | closed_claims|
+------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|       1    |       3      |        0        |      1    |      0       |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Current query:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(case when s.stat = 'Pending Assignment' then count(a.clmNo) end,0) as pend_claims,
    ISNULL(case when s.stat = 'Assigned' then count(a.clmNo) end,0) as assnd_claims,        
    ISNULL(case when s.stat = 'QA Ready' then count(a.clmNo) end,0) as qa_ready_claims,
    ISNULL(case when s.stat = 'In QA' then count(a.clmNo) end,0) as qa_claims,
    ISNULL(case when s.stat = 'Closed' then count(a.clmNo) end,0) as closed_claims
FROM assnmts a
inner join assnmtStats astats
    on a.assnmtIdPk = astats.assnmtIdFk
inner join stats s
    on astats.aStatId = s.statIdPk
inner join repAssnmts ra
    on a.assnmtIdPk = ra.assnmtIdFk
inner join aspnetusers anu
    on ra.repId = anu.Id
inner join clients c
    on a.clientIdFk = c.clientIdPk
inner join carrs
    on a.carrierId = carrs.carrIdPk
inner join (SELECT a2.assnmtIdPk, MAX(astats2.asCrtdDt) as MaxDate 
            FROM assnmts a2 
                INNER JOIN assnmtStats astats2
                    on a2.assnmtIdPk = astats2.assnmtIdFk
            GROUP BY a2.assnmtIdPk
            ) mdt
    on a.assnmtIdPk = mdt.assnmtIdPk
    and astats.asCrtdDt = mdt.MaxDate
inner join (select a3.assnmtIdPk, MAX(ra2.raCrtdDt) as MaxRepDate
            from assnmts a3
            inner join repAssnmts ra2
                on a3.assnmtIdPk = ra2.assnmtIdFk
            group by a3.assnmtIdPk
            ) mrepdt
on a.assnmtIdPk = mrepdt.assnmtIdPk
and ra.raCrtdDt = mrepdt.MaxRepDate
group by s.stat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  Remove the `GROUP BY` and rephrase the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT SUM(case when s.stat = 'Pending Assignment' then 1 else 0 end) as pend_claims,
       SUM(case when s.stat = 'Assigned' then 1 else 0 end) as assnd_claims,        
       SUM(case when s.stat = 'QA Ready' then 1 else 0 end) as qa_ready_claims,
       SUM(case when s.stat = 'In QA' then 1 else 0 end) as qa_claims,
       SUM(case when s.stat = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as closed_claims
```